# Does Islam allow parents to abuse their children?

Tags: children, parents

I have tried to search for a hadith or some grounding in the Quran which shuns parents from abusing their own children. I could not find any.

I am talking about verbal and emotional abuse.

I completely understand and have great respect for the rulings in which Islam instructs children to respect their parents and take care of them when they grow old, like they took care of children when they were infants.

But what about children? Don't they have emotions? Don't they have a right to get hurt when they are abused? Does Allah also (na-ooz biALLAH) reject their emotions?
Why does Islam ignore the fact that bullying and abuse at the hands of parents rips a child of any self-esteem and confidence, and results in damaged individuals who spend the rest of their lives and energy getting over the abuse they faced at the hands of their parents, and consequently are never able to reach their full potential?

Answer (score 8):

In islam, parents are never allowed to abuse to mentally torture children. This is against islam. the best in islam is the one having best manners (towards everyone, including their own chidren).

Here is a hadith to support this claim:

> Prophet (peace be upon him) said: “Whoever fails to show mercy to our
>   children and honor to our elders is not one of us.” [Sunan al-Tirmidhî
>   (1919)]

more details here:

http://en.islamtoday.net/artshow-425-3235.htm

Answer (score 1):

Actually rights of children's on parents are more than that of rights of parents on children (I'm forgetting the actual quotation but its something like children rights are 72 and parents rights are 15). Islam never allowed parents to abuse their children.

You must read this answer.
http://www.questionsonislam.com/node/12858

Comment: In that article, most of the content (i.e. everything except the sentences whose references are listed in the end) seems to be based on the opinion of the writer. For example, in the section titled "Treating children well", the writer has not given a single reference. I completely agree with what the writer is saying, but people who abuse their children wouldn't agree. It is the Quran and Hadith which they can't disagree with. I wish there was something in Islam which explicitly established clear boundaries about child abuse at the hands of parents.

Comment: "Islam never allowed parents to abuse their children." - is there something in islam which explicitly rules that parents are Not allowed to abuse (especially emotionally and verbally) their children?

Comment: I have seen a lot of parents who dish out their frustration on their children, in the name of discipline. Will Allah question them about it?

Comment: Islam does not even allow to hit and abuse animal's how could it allow the humiliation of our own children, and yes definitely they need to answer on the day of judgment if they used to do so. The problem here is we heard a lot on how to treat with our parents but a few regarding how to treat our children.

Comment: but that doesn't mean there is no ruling on it as @Farhan, mentioned in hadeeth and if you see my answer and rights of children are 72 as compare to parents only 15, I will send you this narration once I find it completely .

Comment: http://www.ezsoftech.com/stories/parent_corner.asp